# Remove all properties in a deeply nested JavaScript object based on a particular condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have an object that looks something like this (it is an Avro Schema):

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "company.car.v1",
  "name": "CarV1",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "plateNumber",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "ownerId",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name" : "details", 
      "type" : {
            "type" : "record",
            "name" : "DetailsV1",
            "fields" : [
              {
                "name": "engine",
                "type": {
                  "type": "record",
                  "name": "EngineV1",
                  "fields": [
                    {
                      "name": "size",
                      "type": "int",
                      "default": 0
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "valvesCount",
                      "type": "int",
                      "default": 0
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "name" : "color", 
                "type" : "string", 
                "default" : "NONE"
              },
              {
                "name" : "rimSize",
                "type" : "int", 
                "default" : "NONE"
              }
             ]},
             "default" : {}
   },
    {
      "name": "isBrandNew",
      "type": "boolean"
    }
  ]
}
```

My main goal is to have a function that takes such an object as input and extract only some particular fields and produce a subSet of this schema.

So a function that looks something like this `reduceSchema(avroSchema, [paths])`

For example the:

```
function reduceSchema(avroSchemaOnTop, ['ownerId', 'details.engine.size']
```

And then this would produce the `desired output`:

```
{
   "type":"record",
   "namespace":"company.car.v1",
   "name":"CarV1",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"ownerId",
         "type":"string"
      },
      {
         "name":"details",
         "type":{
            "type":"record",
            "name":"DetailsV1",
            "fields":[
               {
                  "name":"engine",
                  "type":{
                     "type":"record",
                     "name":"EngineV1",
                     "fields":[
                        {
                           "name":"size",
                           "type":"int",
                           "default":0
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            ]
         },
         "default":{}
      }
   ]
}
```

Currently I am able to attach a property `keepThisField` to every field (and its parent-tree) that I want to keep, in this case the details.engine.size and ownerId

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "company.car.v1",
  "name": "CarV1",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "plateNumber",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "ownerId",
      "type": "string",
      "keepThisField": "true"
    },
    {
      "name" : "details",
      "keepThisField": "true"
      "type" : {
            "type" : "record",
            "name" : "DetailsV1",
            "fields" : [
              {
                "name": "engine",
                "type": {
                  "type": "record",
                  "name": "EngineV1",
                  "fields": [
                    {
                      "name": "size",
                      "type": "int",
                      "default": 0,
                      "keepThisField": "true"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "valvesCount",
                      "type": "int",
                      "default": 0
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "name" : "color", 
                "type" : "string", 
                "default" : "NONE"
              },
              {
                "name" : "rimSize",
                "type" : "int", 
                "default" : "NONE"
              }
             ]},
             "default" : {}
   },
    {
      "name": "isBrandNew",
      "type": "boolean"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I need now is a mechanism to be able to remove all other fields (in a deeply nested manner) that don't have the property `keepThisField` in them, and then after the `keepThisField` property itself. So we are left with the `desired output`.

Anyone have an idea how one can achieve the removal process in a generic manner in JavaScript?

---

Update:

This is what I have tried with the flatMap:

```
function fn(o) {
  const hasMore = _.get(o, 'type.fields');

  if (o.keepThisField === true) {
    if (hasMore) {
      const retObj = {
        ...o,
        type: {
          ...o.type,
          fields: _.flatMap(o.type.fields, fn),
        }
      };

      _.unset(retObj, 'keepThisField');

      return retObj;
    }

    const cpO = o;
    _.unset(cpO, 'keepThisField');

    return ({
      ...cpO,
    });
  }

  return [];
}

parentSchema.fields = _.flatMap(parentSchema.fields, fn)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - remove object out of nested Object array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63468530/javascript-remove-object-out-of-nested-object-array)

Comment: @Kinglish Not really, mine is not nested arrays directly, is more like fields[].type.fields instead of fields[].fields

Comment: Have you made an attempt at this? What was your approach? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Kinglish I have updated my description. Look at the end.

Answer (score 0):

[Answering my own question]

A potential solution for the removal part of the process. Credits to @Kinglish for the reference to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63468530/javascript-remove-object-out-of-nested-object-array) to use the flatMap.

```
function fn(o) {
  const hasMore = _.get(o, 'type.fields');

  if (o.keepThisField === true) {
    if (hasMore) {
      const retObj = {
        ...o,
        type: {
          ...o.type,
          fields: _.flatMap(o.type.fields, fn),
        }
      };

      _.unset(retObj, 'keepThisField');

      return retObj;
    }

    const cpO = o;
    _.unset(cpO, 'keepThisField');

    return ({
      ...cpO,
    });
  }

  return [];
}

parentSchema.fields = _.flatMap(parentSchema.fields, fn)
```